# AngularJS: Callbacks defined properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, ionic-framework, steroids

I'm trying to print a list of objects showing their names and the distance between its and the users location. I do retrieve the data via GET and calculate the distance based on the latitudes and longitudes. However, the length of my scope-array remains 0. I guess there's something wrong with my callback architecture but i can't seem to figure it out.

Controller:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).controller('objectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.objects = [];
$http.get('http://url.com/getobjects.php').then(function (resp) {
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.data.length; i++) {
        getDistance(resp.data[i].lat, resp.data[i].lng, (function(index){
            return function(dist){
                $scope.objects[index] = {
                    name: resp.data[index].name,
                    distance: dist
                };
            }
        })(i));
    }
}, function (err) {
    console.error('ERR', err);
    alert("error");
});
```

GetDistance:

```
function getDistance(lat2, lon2, callback) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function onSuccess(position) {
        var lat1 = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon1 = position.coords.longitude;
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180;
        var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1 / 180;
        var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2 / 180;
        var theta = lon1 - lon2;
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        dist = dist * 1.609344;
        callback(dist);
    }, function onError(error) {
        alert("no location found:"+ error);
    });
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `getDistance` callback appears out of the $digest cycle. So you should try to kick it off manually:

```
$scope.objects[index] = {
    name: resp.data[index].name,
    distance: dist
};
$scope.$apply();
```

or using `$timeout` service:

```
getDistance(resp.data[i].lat, resp.data[i].lng, (function (index) {
    return function (dist) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.objects[index] = {
                name: resp.data[index].name,
                distance: dist
            };
        });
    }
})(i));
```

Comment: Which one of those 2 is the "better" way? I've now implemented the first one (works great) as I suppose I can avoid an addtional function definition. Is my assumption correct? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The second one is more reliable since it doesn't try to run a digest until the previous one is done. So there will be no "$digest already in progress" error.

Comment: Please don't use `$apply`, it's very seldom a good practice. Just wrap `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` with a `$q` promise and no $apply/$timeout will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
        $scope.objects[index] = {
            name: resp.data[index].name,
            distance: dist
        };
```

Replace

```
        $scope.objects.push({
            name: resp.data[index].name,
            distance: dist
        });
```